# Python Skier Program

Tags: python, macos, pygame

This is my first game, and I've run up on some problems.  I have all the files I need. The pygame window opens up like it is going to start the game, then it just gives me the beach ball of death! lol! The error codes are below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mhallfamily/Desktop/Python Folder/Skier.py", line 81, in <module>
    skier = SkierClass()

  File "/Users/mhallfamily/Desktop/Python Folder/Skier.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.image = pygame.image.load ("skier_down.png")
error: Couldn't open skier_down.png
```

Here is my program!

```
#First Game!!!!

import pygame, sys, random

skier_images = ["skier_down.png", "skier_right1.png",
                "skier_right2.png", "skier_left2.png",
                "skier_left1.png"]

class SkierClass (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self) :
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        import os
        print (os.getcwd(), os.path.exists("skier_down.png"))
        self.image = pygame.image.load ("skier_down.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect ()
        self.rect.center = [320, 100]
        self.angle = 0

    def turn(self, direction) :
        self.angle = self.angle + direction
        if self.angle < -2:    self.angle = -2
        if self.angle > 2:    self.angle = 2
        center = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.load(skier_images[self.angle])
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = center
        speed = [self.angle, 6 - abs(self.angle) *2]
        return speed

    def move (self, speed):
         self.rect.centerx = self.rect.centerx + speed[0]
         if self.rect.centerx < 20: self.rect.centerx = 20
         if self.rect.centerx < 620: self.rect.centerx = 620

class ObsticalsClass (pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, type) :
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__ (self)
        self.image_file = image_file
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image_file)
        self.location = loacation
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = location
        self.type = type
        self.passed = False

        def scroll (self, t_ptr):
            self.rect.centery = self.location[1] - t_ptr

def creat_map(start, end):
    obsticals = pygame.sprite.Group()
    grates = pygame.sprite.Group()
    locations = []
    for i in range (10):
        row = random.randit (start, end)
        col = random.randit (0, 9)
        location = [col * 64 + 20, row * 64 + 20]
        if not (location in locations) :
            locations.append(location)
            type = random.choice(["tree", "flag"])
            if type == "tree": img = "skier_tree.png"
            elif type == "flag":  img = "skier_flag.png"
            obstacle = ObstacleClass (img, location, type)
            obstacles.add(obstacle)
    return obstacles
def animate ():
    screen.fill ([255, 255, 255])
    pygame.display.update (obstacles.draw(screen))
    screen.blit (skier.image, skier.rect)
    screen.blit(score_text, [10 ,10])
    pygame.display.flip()

def updateObstacleGroup (map0, map1):
    obstacles = pygame.sprite.Group()
    for ob in map0: obstacles.add (ob)
    for ob in map1: obstacles.add (ob)
    return obstacles

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode ([640, 640])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
skier = SkierClass()
speed = [0, 6]
map_position = 0
points = 0
map_position = 0
map0 = create_map (20, 29)
map1 = create_map (10, 19)
activeMap = 0
obstacles = updateObstacleGroup (map0, map1)
font = pygame.font.Font (None, 50)


while True:
    clock.tick (30)
    for event in pygame.event.get ():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                speed = skier.turn (-1)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                speed = skier.turn (1)
    skier.move (speed)
    map_position += speed [1]

    if map_position >=640 and activeMap == 0:
        activeMap = 1
        map0 = creat_map (20, 29)
        obstacles = updateObsstacleGroup (map0, map1)
    if map_position >=640 and activeMap == 0 :
        activeMap = 0
        for ob in map0:
            ob.location[1] = ob.location [1] -1280
        map_position = map_position - 1280
        map1 = create_map (10, 19)
        obstacles = updateObstaclesGroup (map0, map1)

for obstacles in obstacles:
    obstacles.scroll (map_position)

hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide (skier, obstacles, False)
if hit:
    if hit [0] .type == "tree" and not hit [0] .passed:
        points - 100
        skier.image = pygame.image.load ("skier_crash.png")
        animate()
        pygame.time.delay(1000)
        skier.angle = 0
        speed = [0, 6]
        hit[0] .passed = True
    elif hit [0] .type == "flag" and not hit [0] .passed:
        points += 10
        obstacles.remove (hit[0])


score_text = font.render ("Score: " +str(points), 1, (0, 0, 0))
animate ()
```

Comment: Does it work if you supply the full path to the images?

Comment: That is the full path. @iCodez

Comment: @user2993901: no, the full path would look something like `"/Users/Fred/somewhere/pics/image.png"`.  To distinguish between some `pygame` error and a simple path error, `import os` and then add `print (os.getcwd(), os.path.exists("skier_down.png"))` right before the image load.

Comment: Also, having your syntax like this `hit [0] .type` may work, but it is going to confuse people.  Normal Python would look like this: `hit[0].type`

Comment: I fixed it above.  it is now giving me a different error code. @DSM

Comment: @user2993901 - Take the full path and place it in `pygame.image.load`.  In other words, change `self.image = pygame.image.load ("skier_down.png")` to `self.image = pygame.image.load ("/full/path/to/file/skier_down.png")`

Comment: @user2993901: The point of adding a `print` is to see what the output is, which you haven't told us.  You also didn't say what the error was.

Comment: I must have something messed up with the .png file.  It keeps saying that it cant open the file.

Comment: The error is    File "/Users/mhallfamily/Desktop/Python Folder/Skier.py", line 81, in <module>
    skier = SkierClass()

Comment: Could you provide the full trace back? And also edit the question as you keep adding information in the comments?

Comment: That is the full trace back, and I am updating it as I edit it.

Comment: I use your code with my bitmaps (all in one folder) and it works. Almost. There is no problem with bitmaps but there are so many typos (letter mistakes) so I doubt that this program was running before.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a folder named `images` that has those images you have downloaded. Make sure that folder is saved in the same place where your code is. If that's the case, try just putting `image/` before each of the image name.

For example rename `"skier_crash.png"` to

```
"images/skier_crash.png"
```

Hope that helps!